# How to split a single column into two in R

Tags: r

I am new to coding in R. I have a large data set where the first column is the date and time separated by a space, and the everything else is separated by a semicolon.

The date file looks as such:

```
20150605 050037;4492;1
```

I have read  this file into a data frame using read.table. The output is as follows.

```
             V1         V2     V3
20150605 050037    4492.00      1
```

Now I would like to split the "V1" column to separate the date and time but I can't seem find an effective way to do it.

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612263/isolating-partial-text-in-r-data-frame/27612561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Hadley's `tidyr` package

```
tidyr::separate(df, "V1", c("date", "time"))
```

Comment: the most elegant solution.